# StackExchange button inbox shows links to deleted answers

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-exchange-button

[image]

Clicking the link takes me to:

[image]

Comment: Good Lord... that's the StackApps 404... I don't even...

Comment: Side effect of the StackApps 404 page gaining a malevolent sentience.  Investigating...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<del>This has been fixed on dev, I will update this answer when its deployed.</del>

Fix has been deployed.

For the curious, the bug was that the deletion "event" wasn't always going to the correct user's inbox.

The orphaned inbox items will remain for the time being, so if you ever wanted alot of Connery at your finger tips you'll have it until its pushed out of the inbox by new activity.